# Referring to XML schemas as RDF namespaces

Tags: xml, rdf, semantic-web, ontology

I am working with RDF and would like to use some of the variables specified in an XML schema. The only [RDF encoding I could find](https://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/GML) of the GML schema I am interested in is severely outdated. As a result it is missing some variables compared with the [latest GML release](http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/).

I would like to use some of the variables present in the GML schema in my RDF data. For example:

```
geom: http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/geometryBasic0d1d.xsd

geom:posList x:hasValue "125"
```

Is it possible to reference schemas in the same way as RDF namespaces? Or is this bad practice? And if this is not possible, does it mean all XML based schemas should be converted into RDF before their contents can be referenced?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "reference"? I mean, in the end you can use URIs and literals for whatever you want. Clearly, a tool for RDF, e.g. a triple store will only consider the RDF triples itself, anything beyond would be non-standard extensions

Comment: @UninformedUser I would just like to know if it's good practice to make reference to XML namespaces in the prefix section of RDF. For instance in this case the posLis variable occurs in a GML schema. So I would make reference to the GML schema document as I have shown in the example.

Comment: You can use the IRIs as you wish - there's an OWL rule that forbids using the standard namespaces to create new entities but nothing about using the IRIs of standard namespaces' entities. The only catch is that you shouldn't expect tools to treat these IRIs as special. Other than that, just consider whether your use might be confusing to others, and whether that's best for your application.